# Disabling Dock in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to disable the dock that pops up in iOS?

This is my View Controller. Notice that it has a draggable view controller in the footer.

[image: screenshot of the view controller]

But when I try to pull it up quickly, the dock shows up:

[image: screenshot of the Dock appearing]

Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: the best practice is to try not to interfere with the system gestures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is iOS 11's [preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys), which will show an indicator at the bottom but not pull up the dock on the first swipe. For example, in your view controller:

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return [.bottom]
}
```

In my experience it still eats the swipe gesture, but it still gives the user a second chance to hit the right target.

On iOS <11 however, this behavior can only be obtained by hiding the status bar.

**Edit:**
Usually when faced with implementing a design choice like this, I try to offer a second, non-interfering gesture as a backup, such as a tap in that area, that has the same effect.

Comment: It is definitely better to leave the user their normal system behavior above your app.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree on that — but unfortunately sometimes we don't always have the final say over what we are asked to implement :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped . Bdw i have decided not to interfare with the system gestures so now using UISwipeGestureRecognizer . This was something new to learn. Thanks

Comment: ^This is a UIViewController method btw.

Answer (score 2):

As in iOS 11, **you cannot disable the dock** in an application, nor in Settings. I'd suggest providing a larger area for swiping up from the bottom.

Comment: Or use a pull from the top or a button, since on iPhone X (and presumably other iOS devices to come), this will literally send the app back to the background.

Answer (score 2):

Normally such conflicts should be avoided, as they degrade user experience: how do you know that the user does not actually want to use the dock?

But if you really want, you can override the `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()` method in the **root** controller to specify which edges should NOT (immediately) trigger system gestures.

e.g.

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return .bottom
}
```

Comment: yes i have decided not to interfare with user experience and found an alternate solution. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this. it's a bit better now, only a small drag up tag is visible. Note that in games, synthesizer apps etc. this undesired dock pop up is really annoying. (e.g. RavelNotes, iMini, Sunrizer). Even that smaller tag shouldn't be visible. But the option whether or not to disable the dock for your app should be left to the user, e.g. in your app settings.